# UIPickerView undeclared?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, datasource, uipickerview

I got a slight problem, I'm getting a error saying "'UIPickerView' undeclared on line 1 of the below code. I copied right out of the book that I have and I'm not sure whats wrong?
could I get some help? it would be greatly appreciated, thanks :)

this is the entire .m file code.

```
#import "InstatwitViewController.h"

@implementation InstatwitViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

activities = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"sleeping",
@"eating", @"working", @"thinking", @"crying", @"begging",
@"leaving", @"shopping", @"hello worlding", nil];

feelings = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"awesome",
@"sad", @"happy", @"ambivalent", @"nauseous", @"psyched",
@"confused", @"hopeful", @"anxious", nil];
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)
pickerView {
return 2;
}
- (NSInteger)PickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerViewnumberOfRowsInComponent :      (NSInteger)component {
if (component == 0) {
    return [activities count];

}
else {
    return [feelings count];
}
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {

[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    switch (component) {
        case 0:

            return [activities objectAtIndex:row];

        case 1:
            return [feelings objectAtIndex:row];

    }
    return nil;

}
}

- (void)dealloc {
[activities release];
[feelings release];
[super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Where* did you copy it? It should be in the `@implementation` ... `@end` section of the `.m` file of the class you are implementing. It should ***not*** be in the `@interface` ... `@end` part, which is typically in a `.h` file, or elsewhere, i.e. *outside* the `@implementation` ... `@end` section.

Please show a little more of your code.

### Edit

This:

```
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {

[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row   forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
```

lacks a closing `}` before `- (NSString *)pickerView: ...`.  In other words, change it thus:

```
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {

    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
```